# How to check the current logging driver for running container in Docker Swarm?

Tags: docker

I am aware how to find out the [current default logging driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62552180/how-to-check-the-current-default-logging-driver-in-docker) for the Docker engine, but according to [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/):

> Changing the default logging driver or logging driver options in the daemon configuration only affects containers that are created after the configuration is changed. Existing containers retain the logging driver options that were used when they were created.

Is there a way of querying the running container in swarm to see which logging driver it is using? I have tried digging through what `docker inspect` is giving me for a given running container but can't see it listed anywhere.

Edit: These are deployed via docker compose into a Docker Swarm.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried digging through what docker inspect

That's, odd it is right ther:

```
    "HostConfig": {
        "Binds": null,
        "ContainerIDFile": "",
        "LogConfig": {
            "Type": "json-file",
            "Config": {}
        },
```

Comment: How was this service deployed to docker @KamilCuk? The ones I am trying with were deployed from docker compose files and did not specify a logging driver in the docker-compose.yml so I don't appear to have that "LogConfig" section.

Comment: `docker run -ti --rm alpine`. `--log-driver none` makes it none there.

Comment: Strange, ok so I can see what you're seeing too if I do that. A further detail I didn't add to my question (will update) is that these are services deployed to docker swarm, so maybe that changes things. I've tried `docker inspect <container_name>` and `docker inspect <container_id>` in case that was it but no cigar.